User WindowInsetsControllerCompat to hide systemBars，But it reappeared after the soft keyboard popped up
I use this way to hide hideSystemBar
In general, it works fine，SystemBar will auto hide
But，after soft keyboard show，SystemBar can't hide
private void hideSystemBar() {
        WindowInsetsControllerCompat insetsController = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(getWindow(), getWindow().getDecorView());

       //These transient system bars will overlay app’s content, may have some degree of transparency, and will   automatically hide after a short timeout
        insetsController.setSystemBarsBehavior(WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE);
        insetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
        
    }

        getWindow().getDecorView().setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                WindowInsetsControllerCompat insetsController = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(getWindow(), getWindow().getDecorView());
                insetsController.setSystemBarsBehavior(WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE);
                insetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            }
        });

so I use this way,but setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener is Deprecated
Is there an alternative to this?

Kotlin version used in my app
    /**
 * This method is responsible to transfer MainActivity into fullscreen mode.
 */
@JvmStatic
fun setToFullScreen(window: Window) {
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

    val insetsController = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)
    insetsController.systemBarsBehavior =
        WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
    insetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars())
    insetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars())
}

part to be inserted in the onCreate method :
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout)
    //
    if (supportActionBar != null) {
        supportActionBar!!.hide()
    }
    /*
    USED FOR FULL SCREEN
    */
    mywindow = getWindow()
    setToFullScreen(mywindow)

